# define max lines for wrapping textbox

Tags: python, widget, word-wrap, urwid

`urwid` has a number of different widgets that allow text to be displayed, and a [few ways to format the text](http://urwid.org/reference/text_layout.html#urwid.TextLayout) to the window size.  How can I format the text of a widget to wrap the first line and truncate the second?  To be specific:

```
`a rather long string that is wrapped on the first line and clipped on the second'

           (window boundary)
|-------------------------------------|
|a rather long string that is wrapped |
|on the first line and clipped on t...|
|-------------------------------------|
```

Of course this could be done manually by counting chars, but that would get ugly quickly, esp. with window resizing.

Comment: interesting question... can you share a sample code w/ what you've tried?

Comment: If you're on Python 3, maybe you could get away using text processing stuff available in [textwrap](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/textwrap.html) ?

Comment: I think `textwrap` is a good suggestion.  I'll post sample code later.

Comment: An interesting note: if your original string contains newline characters, these *don't* get stripped by `wrap='clip'` and the rendered `Text` will extend several lines.  For multiline string input it then maybe stripping all but the first `\n` and `wrap='clip'` would be a more reasonable solution.  I haven't tried this yet.